# My Android ArrayList shows only last added value

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList<String> tokens;` to store token values on ListViewClick. after adding values when i retreive the data from `ArrayList<String> tokens` it shows only the last added value

```
ArrayList<String> tokens;
...
....
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String selectedtoken = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ContactToken"));

            tokens.add(selectedtoken);
        }
...
...
Log.i("array: ", tokens.toString()); // shows the last added value
```

Comment: Wrong initialization of the code `tokens = new ArrayList<String>();`. you need to do the initialization at the class level.

Answer (score 5):

Move the statement

```
tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
```

out of the `onItemClick` method preferably into a constructor so its not being re-initialized every time that method is called, e.g.

```
public MyClass() {
   tokens = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

where `tokens` could be defined as

```
private List<String> tokens;
```

Answer (score 5):

You must move the initialization of your `ArrayList` outside the `onItemClick()` method. Currently each time you click on an item, you create a new `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
...
....
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,int position, long id) {

    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    String selectedtoken = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("ContactToken"));

    tokens.add(selectedtoken);
}
...
...
Log.i("array: ", tokens.toString()); // shows the last added value
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize Arraylist in onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, that your try to access your information before tokens is initializied.

You have to move it. For example to the onCreate-Method.

Also possible is to move it to the constructor.

The third way would be to change this:

```
ArrayList<String> tokens;
```

to this:

```
ArrayList<String> tokens= new ArrayList<String>();
```